# AutoIT - Check if Javascript is present

Tags: autoit

I am working on a program in which it Automates the functionality of a website. I came across an issue wherein I want to see if a JavaScript function is present on a page.

```
javascript:showBranchLPA(0)
```

If that is present on the page it'll call out another function. Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use _IEDocReadHTML, and then check the source using stringinstr()

Comment: Tried that as well but that only searches the whole HTML within the page and does not include the functions or external functions from another .js file.